# Show a most recently used tab after dragging a tab in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In IntelliJ IDEA, I want to show a most recently used tab after **dragging** a tab like eclipse. For example,

```
a.java
b.java
c.java(Current)
...
d.java(Previous) -- hidden by dropdown
```

In case 'c.java' was dragged, the editor shows 'a.java' instead of 'd.java'.

I want it to behave same as 'Activate most recently opened' setting for closing tabs. But it doesn't work for dragging in case the previous tab is hidden by a dropdown menu. Is there any setting for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no setting for it.